# Refresh data during a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting data from a sheet and want to get it displayed on another sheet in order to check if something has to be done in the near future.

I am scanning all the data that have the "TO PLAN" case and register those that meet the specification in my sheet.

The problem is that each data-point overwrites the previous one - only the last data point is displayed.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRowS2 As Long
Dim lastRowS3 As Long

lastRowS2 = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 5
For j = i To lastRowS2
    Select Case Sheets(2).Range("O" & j)
        Case Is = "-"
        Case Is = "TO PLAN"
        lastRowS3 = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(3).Range("A" & lastRowS3) = Sheets(2).Range("C" & j)

    End Select
'MsgBox j
Next j
```

Is there a way to get all the data that match the condition properly displayed ?

Thanks for help and excuse me about my English, I am kind of rusty.

Comment: use `Sheets(3).Range("A" & lastRowS3 + 1)`. Or `lastRowS3 = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`

Comment: My awnser is essentialy that, slightly different aproach tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expanding my comment, your code could be refactored as follows (explanations in comments):

```
Dim j As Long ' use "Long" (spanning to some +/- 2 billions) instead of "Integer" type (spanning to some +/- 32k)

With Sheets(2) ' reference your sheet object
    For j = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' each object with after a "dot" is the child of the referenced one (in this case: Sheets(2))
        Select Case .Range("O" & j)
            Case Is = "-"
            Case Is = "TO PLAN"
                Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = .Range("C" & j).Value
        End Select
    Next
End With
```

you could also avoid looping and use `Autofilter()` method:

```
With Sheets(2) ' reference your sheet object
    With .Range("A4:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) ' reference referenced sheet range spanning from "O4" to column A last not empty cell 
        .AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:="TO PLAN"' filter referenced range on its 15th filed (column O) with "TO PLAN" value
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy referenced range first column filtered cells skipping first row (header) to Sheet(3) column A first empty cell after last not empty one
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```